# Naive Bayes and SVM java implementation for document classification

Tags: java, svm, document-classification, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I am trying to classify legal case documents which are in text format, in different folders like Civil, Land, Criminal, e.t.c, I intended using Naive Bayes as Vectoriser to get the vectors from the text documents,feed it in to SVM to classify the documents using javaml, I have implemented the preprocessing like stemming, I used the formulars of Naive Bayes as seen in http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/2995/1/Isa_Text.pdf to calculate prior probability, likelihood, evidence and posterior probability, I am assuming the posterior probability is the vector to be fed into SVM, but I cannot format the output to feed into the SVM library.

I need all the help I can get in this, I hope I am doing things right.

I have other legal cases as test set that I want to classify to the right categories.

Comment: Do you have a specific question relating to the implementation of your classifier, i.e. something code related? If not, you may get more help on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, I have, I cant paste the codes here, its too big for this page, how do I attach a text document, so that I can show the code, its too long to paste here

Comment: First of all, Am I right to feed in the posterior probability gotten from Naive Bayes for my documents to my SVM as feature vectors, If Yes, how do I feed it into javaml or libsvm to be able to train and classify my test legal cases?